# android edittext программно установить язык ввода

Tags: android, android-edittext

Есть два EditText

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/word"
    android:layout_below="@+id/wordCaption"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="enteredEnglish"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
```

и второй

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/translate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/translateCaption"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="enteredRussian"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:digits="абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ.,"
    />
```

**проблема со вторым**: мне надо, что бы там только русский язык для ввода был доступен, а выдается английский, как в первом

пробовал еще вариант:

```
   mTranslate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.translate);
    mTranslate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    mTranslate.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"));
```

но он тоже не работает - на моем телефоне вообще одни цифры показывает.
Подскажите куда копать?
Или, может быть, последовательность кривая, тогда какая верная?
Спасибо

ps: забыл добавить, тестировал на android 4.4.2, телефон Asus ZenFone 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не удастся форсировать изменение клавиатуры на русский + у пользователя просто может не быть нужной клавиатуры (русские раскладки совершенно разные в зависимости от поставщика)

Вы можете узнать какой язык в данный момент используется:

```
InputMethodSubtype ims = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE).getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
String locale = ims.getLocale();
```

И если активна не русская раскладка, то показать предложение сменить язык.

Также, если вам просто необходимо показать именно русский без альтернативных опций, то посмотрите в сторону [создания кастомного `Input Method`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)

Comment: спасибо, попробую кастомный сообразить